# Scan all the files and Display the name and path of the file with the maximum size

Tags: java, netbeans

It is a program (Java) that uses system calls to extract basic information related to the system.

> Scan all the files and Display the name and path of the file with the maximum size

Can someone please help i am confused with the system calls. 
THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what tou need. But you should read documentation about FILE API  . http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

```
public class ListFiles 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        // Directory path here
        String path = "."; 

        String files="";
        double maxBytes = 0;
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
        {

            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile() && listOfFiles[i].length()>maxBytes) 
            {
                maxBytes = listOfFiles[i].length()
                files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(files);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look at [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Take a look at:

- [`File#listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29)
- [`File#length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29)
- [The `for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

If you're very brave and have the time, you could also take a look at the [File I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) API available in Java 7

Comment: THanks very much that realy help to understand :)